# GPX from geotagged photos

Tags: photos, geotagging

Is there a way to create a GPX track from a batch of geo-tagged photos, taking the image creation time and location as the track points?

There are a few programs that geo-tag photos from a stored GPS log (GPX, for example), but I would like it the other way around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All right, I built a Node.js application that does just that: https://github.com/JanisE/gpx-from-images.